# Virtualbox 4.1.12 Unable to connect to network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian

I'm trying to create a Vagrant Basebox for Debian Lenny.

The first step in this process is creating a VM Guest in Virtualbox. I've created a new VM image and begun installation of Debian Lenny using the netinst image.

However, the VM refuses to connect to the network.

My Ubuntu host has a standard ethernet network connection with full internet access.

After configuring the root and non-root users, the non-GUI installer prompts me to select a mirror for downloading additional packages.

Regardless of the mirror seleceted, the following message is displayed:

**Bad archive mirror
The specified Debian archive mirror is either not available, or does not hae a valid Release file on it. Please try a different mirror.**

I have tried 2 network configurations for the VM Guest by right-clicking on the guest item listed in **VirtualBox Manager -> Settings -> Network**. The first is the default configuration, this being:

```
Attached to: NAT
```

The second was:

```
Attached to: Bridged Adapter

Name: eth0

Promiscuous Mode: Deny
```

Neither has any effect.

I chose to continue the installation anyway, so am now in the Lenny guest OS.

Is there a simple fix to enable networking for this VM?

Sincere thanks for your time.

Comment: What did you see in the virtual terminal '4' as error ? To switch you need to enter ALT+F4 and ALT+F1 to restore to first. I bet you'll see an error about getting the 'Release' file on mirror which I've been also bitten by. So, it's not a network issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is with network interface driver in guest OS, try changing adapter type in **VirtualBox Manager -> Settings -> Network -> Advanced**. I had similar problem with windows as guest and choosing PCnet-PCI II solved the problem.